# What good is Rapid Grappler's swift action to an animal?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, grapple, animals

If a T-Rex animal companion has [Greater Grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-grapple-combat-final/) and [Rapid Grappler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/rapid-grappler-combat/), what could it do with the swift action? I'm assuming it would not have the finesse required to tie up a foe, so I'm not sure what there is left for the Rapid Grappler swift action to be used for.

Chain of events:

1. Standard action Grapple (grapple foe)
2. Move action Greater Grapple (pin foe)
3. Swift action Rapid Grappler (tie up foe?) ← what are a T-Rex's options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes from the grappling rules:

> Once you are grappling an opponent, a successful check allows you to continue grappling the foe, **and also** allows you to perform one of the following actions (as part of the standard action spent to maintain the grapple).

Emphasis added.

If your opponent is already pinned and tying them is not possible, the options in the grappling rules are moving the opponent or damaging them (with for example a natural weapon).

I don't see anything in the rapid grappling feat that limit the options. Hence: move the target or bite them.